# How does warehouse size change automatically in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, autoscaling, warehouse

I have a small warehouse in SnowFlake, with `minimum clusters = 1`, `maximum clusters = 5` and `scaling policy` set to `standard`. However, when I was viewing the query history profile, I saw that for some of the queries, `size` column was set to `large`, but the `cluster number` remained 1.

Now, I know that autoscaling helps increasing number of clusters, but how did the warehouse size change for some queries without manual intervention?

I referred to the official documentation of SnowFlake [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-multicluster.html#multi-cluster-size-and-credit-usage), but couldn't find any ways to automatically change size of warehouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake [does not carry any feature](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z000097YkNbSAK/warehouse-size-remove-the-dynamically-change-of-setting) that will automatically alter the size of your warehouse.

It is likely that the tools in use (or users) may have run an [`ALTER WAREHOUSE SET WAREHOUSE_SIZE=LARGE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-warehouse.html). The purpose may have been to prepare for a larger operation, ensuring adequate performance temporarily.

Use the various [history views](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) to find out *who/what* and *when* such a change was run. For example, the [`QUERY_HISTORY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) view could be useful in finding the username and role that was used to alter the warehouse size, with the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_name, role_name, query_text, session_id, start_time
FROM snowflake.account_usage.query_history
WHERE query_text ILIKE 'ALTER%SET%WAREHOUSE_SIZE%=%LARGE%'
AND start_time > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '7 days';
```

Then you could use [`LOGIN_HISTORY`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/login_history.html) view to find which IP the user authenticated from during the time (or use the [history UI](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html) for precise client information), check all other queries executed [in the same session](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html), etc.

To prevent unauthorized users from modifying warehouse sizes, consider [restricting warehouse-level grants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#virtual-warehouse-privileges) on their roles (rolename in use can be detected by the query above).

Comment: Thanks @Harsh. I saw that the some user configured in the system itself was running the alter warehouse command. It probably is a process which increases the warehouse size subject to certain conditions.